# How do I prevent hg update <branch> without committing in the active branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, branch

Let's say I have 2 branches on my local repo, case1 and case2. I'm currently working on case1 and have uncommitted changes.

When I `hg up case2` I want this navigation to be prohibited unless I have made the choice of committing my changes in case1 or not.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You will probably need to write a little mercurial extension in python for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you `hg up case2` with uncommitted changes, and `case2` is no direct ancestor/descendant of `case1`, Mercurial will refuse to do it with

```
abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --clean to discard changes)
```

You can then opt for either committing your changes, discard them by means of using the proposed option or update to the common ancestor of `case1` and `case2`. The later case is a two-hop approach to take the uncommitted changes with you while you hop to case2.

In addition, newer versions of Mercurial have the `--check` option for the update command. This will do exactly what you wanted: abort the command in case your working copy is dirty.

Of course, all this is pretty obvious if you check `hg help update`.

Comment: Updating to the common ancestor: `hg update -r "ancestor(., case2)"`. You can even create an alias for this.